# Problema al actualizar registros en mysql desde nodejs express

Tags: mysql, nodejs

```javascript
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const mysql = require('mysql')
const myconn = require('express-myconnection')
const routes = require('./routes')
const cors = require('cors')

app.set('port', process.env.Port || 9000)
const db = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: '3306',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'vinedopos'
}

app.use(myconn(mysql, db, 'single'))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())


app.use('/', routes)

app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log('Server running on port', app.get('port'))
})
```

```javascript
//Actualizar registro
routes.put("/factura/linea/", (req, res) => {
  req.getConnection((err, conn) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.send(err);
    } else {
      conn.query(
        "UPDATE lineafactura set Cantidad=?, Subtotal=? WHERE LineaFacturaID = ?",
        [req.body.Cantidad, req.body.Subtotal, req.body.LineaFacturaID],
        (err, linea) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.send(err);
          } else {
            console.log(linea);
          }
        }
      );
    }
  });
});
```

¿Existe alguna configuración en MySQL la cual luego de varias modificaciones de registros deje de realizar los cambios?, Las query´s provienen de un servidor de nodejs el cual adjunté, junto con el metodo que realiza la actualización de registros.
El problema lo noto luego de realizar varias modificaciones de un mismo registro, ya que el servidor se queda como en un bucle sin obtener respuesta.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: No veo que retornes ninguna respuesta al cliente cuando se actualiza un registro.

Comment: Correcto porque no lo necesito en este caso en concreto, ya que lo que se debe ver se realiza por medio de otro método.

Comment: Pero una solicitud `http` se considera completa cuando hay una respuesta del servidor. En el código que muestras no hay respuesta para el caso de actualización del registro, por lo tanto la solicitud no se completa y el navegador se queda "pillado" esperando dicha respuesta. :/

Comment: Bro muchisimas gracias, literal ese era el error, inspeccioné y resulta que si estaba esperando respuesta para finalizarse. Muchas gracias.